# Continuity ( Find unknown)

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f(x) = a \sin \{(pi/2)(x+1)\}$ if $x \leq 0$

$(tan x - sin x)/x^3$ if $x > 0$

$f(x)$ is continious at $x = 0$
find a

I did like this --->

```
lim f(x) = a
x->0+
lim   (tan x - sin x)/x^3 = a
x->0+
put x = 0 + h
lim (tan h - sin h)/h^3 = a
h->0
lim (tan h)/h^3 - lim (sin h)/h^3 = a
h->0              h->01
lim tan h / h  .  lim 1/h^2 -  lim sin h / h  .  lim 1/h^2 = a
h->0              h->0         h->0              h->0
lim (1/h^2) - (1/h^2) = 0 = a
h->0
implies that a = 0
```

As $\lim_{h \to 0} \tan h/h = 1$

$lim \sin_{h \to 0} h/h = 1$

but a does not equal 0 it equals 1/2
where is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

for the second limes write
$$\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos(x))(1+\cos(x)}{x^3\cos(x)(1+\cos(x))}$$
and this tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x$ tends to Zero, so $a=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: OK but where does I go wrong, why it can't be 0

Comment: since the limites $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tan(h)}{h^3}$$ and $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)}{h^3}$$ do not exist